# Get IP address of host where docker engine is running

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

From within a running docker container, is there a way to get IP address of the host on which the container is running?

Answer (score 3):

From within the container, the address of your default gateway is *an* address of the host. You can get that, for example, like this:

```
ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}'
```

That is your host's address on the bridge device that Docker created for your container network.  You will be able to access any host services at that address that are either listening on all interfaces or that are are bound to that specific interface.

If you *really* need an external address of your host, you would need to pass that information in via an environment variable, like this:

```
docker run -e MY_IP=192.168.10.1 ...
```

Or via some other mechanism (configuration file, database value, etc).

Answer (score 0):

larsks's answer is great. But if you need to get the public IP of host, you can try http://ifconfig.me/ . The command will be:

```
$ curl ifconfig.me
```

Then you can get the public IP of your host.